# Use .NET 4.0 or .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net

Windows 7 and Vista have the .NET 2.0/3.5 language runtime installed, so whatever you code in 3.5 will run on Windows 7 and most of it on Vista, too. But Windows 8 only delivers the .NET 4.0 CLR. When executing an assembly build with .NET 3.5, Windows 8 would need to install the .NET 3.5 runtime.
This would be a contra for .NET 3.5, but a contra for .NET 4.0 would be the low market share on Windows 7 and below.

What .NET framework should be used if you want high compatibility?

Comment: Isn't .NET 4.0 downward compatible?

Comment: Windows Vista ships with .NET Framework 3.0

Comment: Yes it is. The only promblem was going back beyond 1.1

Comment: .NET 4.0 is a different CLR from .NET 3.5 (which is CLR 2.0)

Comment: @Devils, I am not certain ur concern here - if compatibility is the case then clearly .NET 4 is a winner as its latest version, backward compatible and will be present with new OS. If concern is forcing user to download & install .NET Fx then you are not taking windows XP into account (that has 45% share world-wide, 28% in USA - see http://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?qprid=10&qpcustomd=0) - XP does not include .NET 3.5/4.0 out of box. So I wouldn't worry too much about download part if that's the concern.

Comment: Are there any statistics which OSes have what .NET version installed on the average computer? If .NET really is widely installed, it would be no matter, but I doubt that. Still I didn't find any statistics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx) you won't need to install 3.5 on Windows 8 as it is backward-compatible:

> The .NET Framework 4 is backward-compatible with applications that were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5. In other words, applications and components built with previous versions of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.

Also, this question might be of intrest:
https://serverfault.com/questions/121563/are-net-versions-backwards-compatible.

Comment: I've tested the consumer preview of Windows 8 and I did need to install .NET 3.5 when executing a .NET 3.5 compiled executable. In that matter it would be very interesting to know how many machines have .NET 4.0 installed by today.

Comment: True.  I developed using 3.5 and when run on a vanilla Windows 8 machine the app refused to run and 3.5 had to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it really depends on how you intend to deploy your application. 
I believe using the .net 4.0 can only be a good idea, because installing a newer version of the framework is really easy, especially using the built in deployement tools in VS.

So why go for an "older" framework, when you have the possibility of using a better version ? Will you be getting any benefits from using the 4.0 instead of the 3.5 ?

I believe yes, but maybe not, in which case you could go for the 3.5

Answer (score 2):

I think the question goes into the direction, what framework will be supported "out of the box" by the OS. But as you already noted their is no common base between the different OSes. All you can do is built a setup project that checks for the requirements.

But i think you should go with .Net 4 cause it has the smallest footprint needed for a installation. For further informations you could check out [smallestdotnet](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/).

Answer (score 1):

.Net even supports side by side execution.
Have a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx) article for details.
So running code >=2.0 will be not a problem for future versions.
3.5 is a reasonable choice, if you do not need TPL.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that 4 .NET includes all preceding versions of framework starting from 1.0. But seems like 3.5 should be [explicitly "enabled"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Windows 8. Anyway 4.0 is the best option.